# Why does it not recognise -version as a command

Tags: discord.py

When I do -version it says discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "version" is not found.

my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.errors import Forbidden
from discord import member

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', help_command=None)

@client.command
async def version(ctx):
    await ctx.send("TimmyBot's current version is 1.4")
```

Answer (score 3):

## You missed the () after @client.command

Change

```py
@client.command
async def version(ctx):
    await ctx.send("TimmyBot's current version is 1.4")
```

to

```py
@client.command()
async def version(ctx):
    await ctx.send("TimmyBot's current version is 1.4")
```

#### Why?

client.command is a function that returns a decorator. to use that function, you must call it, therefore the ()